# Dispatch with sbt 0.11 gives sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency

Tags: sbt

Update:

### I was using SBT 0.11 while "sbt 0.12" is required. a update of SBT does the job!

I followed [the steps to install Dispatch with sbt](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html).

```
$ echo 'libraryDependencies += "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.11.0"' > build.sbt
```

When I ran:

```
$ sbt console
```

I got the following error message:

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: net.databinder.dispatch#dispatch-core_2.10.0;0.11.0: not found
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Could you either delete the question or post the answer yourself and accept it please? (Otherwise it shows up in the Unanswered section)

Comment: @EugeneYokota Guess we should create a community Wiki answer and include the update. WDYT?